# Set Data for Select2 Kartik Optgroup

Tags: php, yii2

Basically I have data that came from MySQL query with keyword union all.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($listNoEstimate as $k => $v) {
    $result[$v['id']][] = $v['no_surat'] . ' - ' . $v['level'];
}
```

This is the data

```
print_r($data);


Array
(
[1904] => Array
    (
        [0] => C0005 - A
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [0] => E1679 - B
        [1] => E1679 - C
    )
)
```

You know, in select2, we can pass data as array like this :

```
echo $form->field($model, 'state_1')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $data,
]);
```

I need like this :

```
<select>
   <optgroup label = 'C0005'>
      <option value = '1904'> C0005 - A </option>
   </optgroup>

   <optgroup label = 'E1679 '>
      <option value = '16'> E1679 - A </option>
      <option value = '16'> E1679 - B </option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

use php `foreach` :

```
echo '<select>'
foreach( $data as $key => $value ){
   echo '<optgroup label = '.$value.'>'
   foreach($value as $v){

      echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$v.'</option>'

    }
    echo '</optgroup>'
}

echo '</select>'
```

I have not tested it, hope you get the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Update foreach

```
foreach ($listNoEstimate as $k => $v) {
        $result[$v['no_surat']]['id'] = $v['no_surat'] . ' - ' . $v['level'];
    }
```